# Postgresql - Have to add all values to table at once?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently making a database in Postgresql and have been having many issues. It will only allow me to insert data in all of the columns at the same time. If I insert data into some of the columns, then try to add data to another column in the same column I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (101, null, 23, 5, 65, 6, null, null).

********** Error **********

ERROR: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
SQL state: 23502
Detail: Failing row contains (101, null, 23, 5, 65, 6, null, null).
```

Even though it says theres a null value in the name column I populated that column with data. This is very frustrating! If anyone has any idea what might be causing this that would be very helpful!

Comment: Are you using an `INSERT INTO` statement to update the empty fields on the existing record, or are you using an `UPDATE <table>` statement to update them?

Comment: was using insert into

Comment: `INSERT INTO` is to create a new record. But once that record exists and you wish to update a field on the existing record, you have to use [UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html). It will look like `UPDATE <table> SET field1='somevalue', field2='somevalue' WHERE "name"='the-name-on-the-record-you-are-updating'`

Comment: Please provide the actual query and the relevant parts of your database schema (at least the output of `\d table_name`)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have constraints on your table you will run into errors like that.
If you need to join to another table to retrieve the missing data, consider using the `INSERT INTO ___ SELECT ___` syntax.  It will allow you to fully populate your data before inserting it into the target table.

If that's not an option, make a temporary staging table for the new records that has no constraints.  Insert the records there, update them, then insert them into the main table.

Comment: OP was attempting to Update empty fields on existing records with an `INSERT` statement. I believe OP was getting CRUD operations confused.